# ASP.net for desktop application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was talking with a friend the other day, and he was saying to me that it is able to create desktop based software in ASP.net. With what I know, ASP.net is only for web-pages. I made few searches around the google, and most of the results say it is a web designing page. But there was many others who said it can, but need to use 3rd party desktop or something..

So, I am asking here to get a better answer. Is it possible to create a computer based software in ASP.net?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a desktop app (with WPF for example) that has a WebBrowser control to host your asp.net site.

but yes, asp.net is at the end a web technology.

read more about: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In theory it is possible. You run a web server and get a browser shell to communicate with the web server on localhost. This is of course stupid but possible. Also he is probably talking about .NET, not ASP.NET which makes much more sense because the desktop frameworks for .NET are pretty good for desktop development.